# R - Weighted Average by Group dplyr Not Working

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate the weighted average by group in R, but it is only returning the weighted average of the whole dataset and I haven't been able to determine where my issue is occurring. Below is my code. Note, in the weighted.mean function, if I do not specify the data frame name for the column type, nothing is returned, so not sure if the way I am referencing the data is causing the issue.

```
unit_averages = selected_units %>% 
  group_by(`Length x Width`,Date) %>% 
  summarise(index_mean = weighted.mean(selected_units$"Wtd Avg Price",w=selected_units$"Unit Count"))
```

Comment: Remove the `selected_units$` and use backquotes for the column names with spaces

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the help, you made my day infinitely better! Didn't realize the difference between backquotes ( ` ) and single quotes ( ' ) which is why I reverted to using "selected_units$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@akrun provided the answer, but they posted as a comment and not an answer, so posting this to close out the inquiry.

> Remove the selected_units$ and use backquotes for the column names with spaces –
> akrun
> Jun 10 at 18:03